# How to know the repo url of each package in package.json in once in CLI?

Tags: json, node.js, npm, repository, command-line-interface

For example if I have this in package.json

```
"autoprefixer": "^7.0.1",
"bower": "^1.8.0",
"browserstack": "^1.5.0",
"canonical-path": "0.0.2",
"cheerio": "^0.22.0",
"clean-css": "^4.1.2",
"colors": "^1.1.2",
"glob": "^7.1.1",
"grunt": "^1.0.1",
```

Is there a way to get repo url of each module in front of it?

Comment: May I know why do you need that?

Comment: @DavidR Wants to add list fo urls in our internal docs

Answer (score 0):

You can get a repo url for all modules in `node_modules` with something like:

```
for i in *; do cat $i/package.json | jq .repository.url; done
```

(this example uses [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/))

But note that not every module has to necessarily have a repo url in the first place.

Also, you will not be bale to get the repo url (even for those that do have it) unless you either do `npm install` or you manually download all of their `package.json` file e.g. with a module like `package-json`:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/package-json